# remove characters in quotes after a particular character jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have a string like this

```
{'Salary':'Basic_Salary - ( ESI * .5 ) - Employee_PF + Bonus','Gross_Salary':'( Salary - Tax )','Employee_PF': ''}
```

If i have another string `'Salary':'',`

I want to replace Salary and get the result

```
{'Salary':'Basic_Salary - ( ESI * .5 ) - Employee_PF + Bonus','Gross_Salary':'( Salary - Tax )','Employee_PF': ''}
```

I can easily check for `'Salary'`. What I am stuck at is, how to replace string in `''` after `'Salary':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically working with JSON object which is coming as a string, in that case you can decode this string to JavaScript object and then modify the properties as any other object

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON({'Salary':'Basic_Salary - ( ESI * .5 ) - Employee_PF + Bonus','Gross_Salary':'( Salary - Tax )','Employee_PF': ''});
```

then :

```
obj.Salary = "Whatever you like";
```

then you can always convert it back to string with

```
JSON.stringify
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "{'Salary':'Basic_Salary - ( ESI * .5 ) - Employee_PF + Bonus','Gross_Salary':'( Salary - Tax )','Employee_PF': ''}";
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    obj.Salary = '';
str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```